# c# Instance method

Tags: c#, methods, instance

i want ;
When form2 is closed, form1 method is called

Form 1;

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

           public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    }
     public void MyMethod()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hi");
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
    }
```

Form 2

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    private Form1 Form1Instance { get; set; }

     private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
            {
                    Form1Instance.MyMethod();
            }
```

error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Where do I make mistakes

thanks

Comment: you aren't creating a `Form1` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of `Form2` to display, you need to assign the `Form1Instance` property to an actual instance of `Form1`. Something like this:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Form1Instance = this;
form2.Show()
```

Which should happen somewhere in your `Form1` class.